# How to copy simulator from different Xcode version?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have 2 XCodes installed on my Mac say Xcode 6.1 and Xcode 5.1. I use Xcode 6.1 iOS  for development. For some bugs raised in iOS 7 I am in the need of iOS 7 simulator. Do I download Xcode 7 simulator When I have my iOS 7.1 simulator with my Xcode 5.1, or Would Xcode 6.1 will work When I copy my simulator from 5.1 to 6.1 ?

If that is possible tell me how?

Tnx in advance

Comment: you need to copy simulators from xcode 5.1 and put in xcode 6.1. otherwise you have to download from xcode preference>Downloads.

Comment: @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani That is what my question is How do you copy form 1 to other?

Answer (score 4):

**For iOS version greater then 13**

`/Applications/OldXcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`

**Copy the simulator sdk you want, and paste it on the same path as above in another XCode version and rename sdk according to version.**

Like For example i have version `13.3` i have to copy it to new xcode with version `13.4`
Following will be the final path `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.3.sdk`

**Also copy the runtime** `iOS.simruntime` from
`/Applications/OldXcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles`

or

`/Applications/OldXcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`

and paste it to the following path

`/Users/waqasahmed/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles`

or

`/Users/waqasahmed/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`

and rename it according to the version like for version 13.3 it will be `iOS 13.3.simruntime`

Comment: I tried your method to copy 13.4 simulator from Xcode 11 to Xcode 12 beta but it didn't work.

Comment: Please check 13.4 will be present in simulator add dialog.

Comment: Using this method I'm able to use the iOS 13.7 Simulators in Xcode 12 as of today. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @WaqasAhmed. I was able to get 12.1 simulators in Xcode 11.3.1 . Only additional thing to do is to open Simulator app from XCode 12 and then go to XCode 11.3 and you will find iPhone 12 simulator in drop down.

Answer (score 2):

Open path:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`

copy the simulator sdk you want, and paste it on the same path as above in another XCode version.

Comment: it worked before, probably something changed in iOS13, not sure

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the necessary simulators in each version of Xcode separately. Can use Xcode>Preference> Downloads option.

Comment: Did you understand my Question?

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to use the iOS 6 simulator runtime in new Xcode 7.  The iOS 6 simulator runtime is not compatible with the new CoreSimulator architecture.